# Push error message to the R Shiny app interface

Tags: r, shiny

Does anyone know how to push the specific error message to the R Shiny interface?

When I run my app in R console, when there is an error, the app will show the specific reason for the error. However, when I deploy my app to the server, when there is an error, all users can see is "An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification.". I'm looking for a solution for this so that my app users can try to troubleshoot themselves when seeing the more specific error message pushed from backstage.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Within your `render` function, you can put something like this:

```
shiny::validate(
            need((nrow(DataSet()) != 0), "No data available based on your selection")
          )
```

You can have as many validate functions that you need and make them as complicated as you need to help the user troubleshoot.

Good reference is [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/validate.html).

Comment: That's helpful to know. I'll have a try. Thanks very much!